# How to watch a promise in angularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

Goal:  $scope.finalArray =  $scope.arrayFromPromise2.concat($scope.arrayFromPromise1);

**First approach**

```
 $scope.arrayFromPromise1 = [];
 $scope.arrayFromPromise2 = [];

 someService.query1()
   .then(function(success){
      $scope.arrayFromPromise1 = success.data;
      return someService.query2();
   })
   .then(function(success){
      $scope.arrayFromPromise2 = success.data;
      $scope.finalArray =  $scope.arrayFromPromise2.concat($scope.arrayFromPromise1);
   });
```

**Second approach**

```
$scope.arrayFromPromise1 = [];
$scope.arrayFromPromise2 = [];

function getData1(){
  someService.query1().then(function(success){
    $scope.arrayFromPromise1 = success.data
  });
}

function getData2(){
  someService.query2().then(function(success){
   $scope.arrayFromPromise2 = success.data;

   $scope.finalArray =  $scope.arrayFromPromise2.concat($scope.arrayFromPromise1);
  });
}

getData1();
getData2();
```

The **Second approach** will throw an error depending on the time of the first promise from *getData1* is finished.
Can use $scope.$watch inside getData2 so I can watch the changes from $scope.arrayFromPromise1 ? Any hints that is different from chaining promises ?

Comment: Did you try/consider including a callback to the `then`? Actually, the second getData should be invoked AFTER the promise from the second is completed.

Comment: Not sure what you suggest, example ?

Comment: Very simple. Invoke the first getData (getData1()) with a promise and a callback which could be getdata2. getData2 should also include a callback that would be invoked upon completion. In this second callback you can implement the concat. What I mean, you should not trigger in parallel two asynchronous processes that need to converge at some point in time, unless you have a mechanism that would synchronize them upon completion (like **rendezvous** in the old Ada language).

Comment: The solution posted by @fdomig is doing what I suggested (serializing the two invocations). I must comment though that I prefer a clearer way of coding.

Comment: The question title is confusing, doesn't reflect the post. Please consider changing it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This (dirty) solution would work:

```
someService.query1().then(function (success1) {
    someService.query2().then(function (success2) {
        $scope.finalArray = success1.data.concat(success2.data);
    });
});
```

### Second solution with $watch

Still dirty, but works:

```
$scope.array1 = [];
$scope.array2 = [];
$scope.finalArray = [];

someService.query1().then(function (success1) {
    $scope.array1 = success.data;
});

$scope.$watchCollection('array1', function (newData, oldData) {
    someService.query2().then(function (success) {
        $scope.finalArray = newData.concat(success.data);
    });
});
```

### Cleaner solution

Use `$q.all()` to wait for multiple promises to get resolved and use the data then to do something:

```
$q.all([someService.query1(), someService.query2()]).then(function (results) {
    $scope.finalArray = results[0].data.concat(results[1].data);
});
```

Comment: it's still a chain...maybe I want to execute just 1 function / query, not both of them

Comment: @VladRadulescu I added another version that `watches` the array1 on changes and then triggers the second query.

Answer (score 4):

Waiting for a bunch of promises to be done and then acting on the info is a simple task using the [$q.all](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) method.

```
//We are returned a promise with a .then block to extract the data
//this is making a certain assumption that we are using the $http service
//where as using another such as $resource or restangular will "unwrap"
//the data for us...

var query1Promise = someService.query1().then(function(res) { return res.data; });
var query2Promise = someService.query2().then(function(res) { return res.data; });

$q.all([query1Promise, query2Promise])
    .then(function(promises) {
         $scope.finalArray = promises[0].concat(promises[1]);
    });
```

Comment: You need to extract the `.data` attribute out of the responses. I would do that in the original assignments: `let query1Promise = someService.query1().then(r => r.data)` so the promises are then promises for the data not promises for the response object or you could do it in the `concat` call..

Comment: @Duncan updated.... but its making a certain assumption. Where as previous the answer is more generic.

Comment: Not pseudo-code, I keep babeljs in my build chain so I use es2016 most of the time. Agreed it makes assumptions (but they match the original question). It would be cleaner if `someService` just returned the data from the query promises rather than passing out the response object.

Comment: No i dont mean the es6 I meant my answer... love the es6 code!

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$scope.finalArray = [];

someService.query1()
   .then(function(response){
      $scope.finalArray = $scope.finalArray.concat(response.data);
   });

someService.query2()
   .then(function(response){
      $scope.finalArray = response.data.concat($scope.finalArray);
   });
```

Both calls will be done asynchronously, in parallel. Whenever one's ready it'll change the `finalArray` on the scope. To ensure the result of query1 is placed before query2 you can play around with what to pass- and call to `concat`.

The advantage is that results from one query can trickle in and cause UI updates before the other one is down. If that's actually a *downside* for your business, then I recommend using the approach from [another answer that utilizes the `all` function](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38094193/419956).

Comment: Thank you for the info sir Jeroen, it really helps me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$q.all()` to wait for both promises, and then concat your results:

```
$q.all([someService.query1(), someService.query2()])
.then(function(dataSet) {
  $scope.finalArray = dataSet[0].data.concat(dataSet[1].data);
});
```

You can use this for as many promises as you need.

Answer (score -1):

How about trying [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all):

```js
var promise = Promise.all([someService.query1(), someService.query2()]);

promise.then(function(result){
   $scope.arrayFromPromise1 = result[0];
   $scope.arrayFromPromise2 = result[1];
  
   $scope.finalArray = $scope.arrayFromPromise2.concat($scope.arrayFromPromise1);
});
```

Comment: The problem with using something like native Promise solution is its outside the scope of angulars digest cycle... aka angular has no idea this took place...